# OK to ask question about where to find free online works?

Tags: discussion

Is it on topic to ask about where to (legally) find a given category of online works? For instance, I'd like to know where (beyond Tor.com) I can find freely available online fantasy short fiction.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry, but that would be a list question, which is generally discouraged on the SE network, and so it would likely be closed as non-constructive.

However, as mentioned in the comments, you should come into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) and ask there.

Comment: +1 - However, [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) wouldn't be a bad place to bring this up.

Comment: Agreed, and I've added that to the answer.